# Adding Points to a previously unselected polyline in Karbon (KOffice)

Tags: kde, vector-graphics, karbon, koffice

Karbon's polyline tool is basically similar to the path tool in Photoshop.  In Photoshop you can alter the path anytime.  Not so with Karbon, so it seems.

Is it possible to add new points to a previously unselecting and reselecting a polyline, or continue it add either end?

Answer (score 0):

You can double click a previously unselected path to edit it.

While in path editing mode, you can double click anywhere on the path to add a new point.